# kubernetes service return refused

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm going to turn crazy. I try to expose my service in kubernetes on Google Cloud. My pods are launch, without errors, my service is created. But when I go on, or curl, I get :

> Failed to connect to 130.***.***.*** port 80: Connection refused

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: k8s-symfony-nginx
  labels:
    name: k8s-symfony-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer #expose
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    type: my-app
```

and replication :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: k8s-symfony-nginx
  labels:
    name: k8s-symfony-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    name: k8s-symfony-nginx
    type: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: k8s-symfony-nginx
        type: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: phpdockerio/nginx:latest
          ports:
            - name: web
              containerPort: 80
        - name: php
          image: gcr.io/myproject-138623/newcom4u/k8s-symfony-php:latest
          ports:
            - name: php
              containerPort: 9000
```

The output of kubectl get svc is :

> k8s-symfony-nginx         10.3.**.**   104.199.**.**   80:30274/TCP
>   4m

The output of kubectl describe on my service is :

```
Name:           k8s-symfony-nginx
Namespace:      default
Labels:         name=k8s-symfony-nginx
Selector:       name=k8s-symfony-nginx,type=my-app
Type:           LoadBalancer
IP:         10.******
LoadBalancer Ingress:   104.*****
Port:           <unset> 80/TCP
NodePort:       <unset> 30274/TCP
Endpoints:      10.0.0.9:80
Session Affinity:   None
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubObjectPath   Type        Reason          Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------   --------    ------          -------
  12m       12m     1   {service-controller }           Normal      CreatingLoadBalancer    Creating load balancer
  11m       11m     1   {service-controller }           Normal      CreatedLoadBalancer Created load balancer
```

Comment: What's the output of `kubectl get svc`?

Comment: k8s-symfony-nginx         10.3.***.***   104.199.***.***   80:30274/TCP   4m

Comment: Can you check kubectl describe output and see if it is indeed bound in the way you expect? It seems like either misconfiguration or firewall rules.

Comment: see my edit, the problem is linked to "Port:           <unset> 80/TCP" ?

Comment: The `<unset>` shouldn't be the issue - have you doublechecked whether the pod actually runs without errors?
E.g. with: `kubectl logs $(kubectl get pods -l name=k8s-symfony-nginx -o name)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i changed

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: k8s-symfony-nginx
  labels:
  name: k8s-symfony-nginx
spec:
type: LoadBalancer #expose
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    type: my-app
```

to

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: k8s-symfony-nginx
  labels:
  name: k8s-symfony-nginx
spec:
type: LoadBalancer #expose
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: my-app
```

type should be changed to app in selector

Comment: Can you explain why changing the label selector to app: my-app worked?

Comment: @Malathi I compared my code with some documentation and found this difference..and just tried it out. Luckily it worked for me. I am not sure why because I am not working with Kubernetes any more..so I didn't dig deeper...